# Mongo Lookup join in collections using $id reference

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called post with references to two other collections: status, format

```
post:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c1c4549c5e277395871ad"),
    "status" : {
        "$ref" : "status",
        "$id" : ObjectId("status123")
    },
    "format" : {
        "$ref" : "format",
        "$id" : ObjectId("format123")
    }
}

status:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("status123"),
    "name" : "Draft"
}

format:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("format123"),
    "name" : "Standard"
}
```

I would like the query for post to return the following:

```
post:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c1c4549c5e277395871ad"),
    "status" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("status123"),
        "name" : "Draft"
    },
    "format" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("format123"),
        "name" : "Standard"
    }
}
```

What should my Mongo Query be? I am new with using MongoDB, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shashi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To  your  question

you can do it like this

```
 db.post.aggregate([
{$project :
           { status:
                    {$arrayElemAt:
                                  [{$objectToArray:"$status"},1]
                     },
            format:
                   {$arrayElemAt:
                                  [{$objectToArray:"$format"},1]
            }}},
{$project:
          {status:"$status.v" ,
          format:"$format.v"}
},

{$lookup : 
          {from :"status" ,
           localField : "status",
            foreignField:"_id" ,
           as :"status"}
},
{$lookup:
          {from :"format" ,
          localField:"format",
          foreignField:"_id",
           as:"format"}
},
{$unwind :"$status"},
{$unwind:"$format"}
])
```

the  result  is looked like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c1c4549c5e277395871ad"),
"status" : { 
           "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c4af7c45316e35251a499"),
             "name" : "Draft" 
            },
 "format" : { 
           "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c4b21c45316e35251a49a"),
            "name" : "Standard" 
           } 
}
```

**explain**

stage1 :  use  `$objectToArray`   to  Converts a document to an array  ,  we  use  it  to  converts the DBref ;
stage2 : use `$arrayElemAt`with `$project` to get the  linked "_id"  .

stage3 : use `$lookup` to join  two collections
stage4 :  use `$unwind`  to get inner document .Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element.

Comment: Why use `$objectToArray`...?   Kinda overkill in this situation, no?

Comment: @HbnKing when I use $unwind, I see that all my posts are not returning and some posts are showing multiple times in the result. I would all my posts returned one and only one time. Can I remove $unwind, that seems to be solving the purpose for me?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti What do you mean by $objectToArray is an overkill? Do you have a better solution in mind?

Comment: ?   Yes, posted below yesterday.  Caveat:  I changed `status.$id` and `format.$id` to `status.id` and `format.id`   I am not sure if the OP cannot do the same, but a data design with leading `$` in the field names is heading for trouble when using the aggregation operators and field path functions.

Comment: use  `$unwind` with  option  like  `{ $unwind: { path: "$sizes", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use `$` in your field names.
But if we use this instead:

```
var sid1 = new ObjectId();
var fid1 = new ObjectId();

var postdoc =
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c1c4549c5e277395871ad"),
    "status" : {
        "ref" : "status",
        "id" : sid1
    },
    "format" : {
        "ref" : "format",
        "id" : fid1
    }
};

var statusdoc =
{
    "_id" : sid1,
    "name" : "Draft"
};

var formatdoc =
{
    "_id" : fid1,
    "name" : "Standard"
};

db.post.insert(postdoc);
db.status.insert(statusdoc);
db.format.insert(formatdoc);
```

then this query:

```
db.post.aggregate([
{$lookup: {"from": "status",
                     localField: "status.id",
                     foreignField: "_id",
                     as: "STATUS" }}

,{$lookup: {"from": "format",
                     localField: "format.id",
                     foreignField: "_id",
                     as: "FORMAT" }}

,{$project: {
        "status": {$arrayElemAt: [ "$STATUS",0 ] },
        "format": {$arrayElemAt: [ "$FORMAT",0 ] }
    }}

                      ]);
```

yields the desired result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c1c4549c5e277395871ad"),
    "status" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c921a32c55e3d729b552f"),
        "name" : "Draft"
    },
    "format" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d7c921a32c55e3d729b5530"),
        "name" : "Standard"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I could get the desired output using variables.

var post = db.post.findOne({"_id":ObjectId("5d7c8fb8ba38a9196e5fc195")})
var dbRef = post.status
var status = db[dbRef.$ref].findOne({"_id":(dbRef.$id)})
var dbRef1 = post.format
var format = db[dbRef1.$ref].findOne({"_id":(dbRef1.$id)})

db.post.aggregate({ $project : { "_id" : post._id , "status" : status , "format" : format}})
```

You can check MongoDB database references link for further information.
    https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/index.html

Comment: That is 3 separate round trips to the database.